# Spring webflow and javascript: bind a form element to a list of strings that may contain commas

Tags: javascript, spring, list

I'm using Spring webflow and I need to get a list of strings out of a form and bound to a list.  Problem is, the strings may contain commas, and my current approach can't deal with that.  The backing object contains a `List<String>` called `values`. The bare bones of my form looks like this:

```
<form:form commandName="backingObject" id="listForm">
    <form:hidden path="values" id="listInput"/>
</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var valuesArray= ["foo", "bar,baz"];
    $('listInput').value = valuesArray;
    $('listForm').submit();    
</script>
```

Problem is, when the array is put in the input, javascript just toStrings it so what comes across as the value is just `"[foo,bar,baz]"` and Spring quite reasonably turns that into a list of three strings.

I've been surprised not to find other people with this problem.  Am I doing something boneheaded?  Solutions I can think of are:

- Uri encode the values before putting them in the array, and unconvert in the backing object.  Feels fragile and hacky, and will make things difficult when other stuff on the Java side interacts with the backing object.
- Make a custom converter, and do something fancier in the javascript when making the input value.  I'm guessing this is the "right" answer but I'm not clear how to proceed.  Possibly I just need to get around to actually reading through the webflow documentation thoroughly. :D
- Just, like, make checkbox inputs on the fly for each value in the list, while waving my arms and yelling "haaaaaaaaack!".

Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, nobody replied, but I went for the multiple inputs solution.  It makes me cringe a bit but it works fine.